# Reading Data from Network Stream

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a simple TCP client and listener code. I want to pass the filename along with the file data. Is there any way to send filename along with file data and reading the filename alone from network stream without corrupting the file data?

Comment: Raw TCP is the last thing I would for such requirement. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm just trying to transfer files. Everything is working fine if i flush filename first followed by actual data.But if i try for concurrency, say 2 transfers at the same time some files are missiong the data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of sending both the filename and data that shouldn't be corrupted. If you use serialization you don't have to manually write and read the file name and contents separately you can just send it and read it as a single object and have the framework deal with serializing and deserializing the individual properties.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
class Data
{
    public string FileName;
    public byte[] FileData;
}
```

Client

```
string filePath = @"c:\temp\myfile.txt";
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("localhost", 8888);

Data data = new Data();
data.FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
data.FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize( client.GetStream(), data);
client.Close();
```

Server

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8888);
listener.Start();
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Data data = (Data)formatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream());
```

Comment: When i try the transfer between different domain after transferring some 200 MB i'm getting "An existing connection was forcibly closed". Firewalls are all disabled. I'm closing all the filestreams, sockets etc